# How do you use VALUES() in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sum

I'm trying to create output that is along the lines of:

```
days_since, item_count
7, 0
30, 1
90, 2
```

and I want to provide the values for `days_since` as a list, something like:

```sql
SELECT d.days, d.item_count
FROM (
    VALUES (7, 0), (30, 1), (90, 2)
) d (days, item_count)
```

except for the `item_count` I need to use `days` as part of a query that counts results for some condition (`is_a_thing`), eg:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN is_a_thing THEN 1 END) AS item_count
FROM items
WHERE created >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

but the date to compare against (30 here) should be `days` from the list.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to join `VALUES` to the `SELECT` and be able to use the former in the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support that syntax (ie you cannot create a derived table with `VALUES()`.

Very recent versions have the `VALUES(ROW ...)` syntax:

```
SELECT d.days, d.item_count
FROM (VALUES ROW(7, 0), ROW(30, 1), ROW(90, 2)) d (days, item_count)
```

In earlier versions, we have to restort `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT d.days, d.item_count
FROM (
    SELECT 7 days, 0 item_count
    UNION ALL SELECT 30, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 90, 2
) d
```

I suspect that the query you want is:

```
SELECT d.days, SUM(CASE WHEN is_a_thing THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)item_count
FROM (VALUES ROW(7), ROW(30), ROW(90)) d (days)
LEFT JOIN items i
    ON i.created >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL d.days
```